# Excel Macros - How do I get Range of AutoFiltered rows?

Tags: excel, filter, vba

OK, so I have set AutoFilter property for the whole of the active worksheet (`UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= [blah blah]`)

Once the filter is applied, how do I programmatically select the range if rows and columns that are the result of the filter.

I checked UsedRange, but that gives the whole (unfiltered) range. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

Comment: rng.Rows.Count shows the number if rows in the filtered range. but rng.Cells property seems to reference the whole range in the sheet